# In Android is it possible to download any file from server directly to /data/data/ path of app?

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I want to download a file from server directly to data/data/ path of my application. Currently I am downloading the file using download manager at external storage. Could you please suggest if there is any way to directly download to data/data/ path of application.

Just to add, Android's default [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) does not provide any option to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you will have to implement your own as no apps except you can access the internal path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm is as follows

1. Create an AsyncTask File
2. Connect to the server Using httpGet or Post
3. Store the Response to the data/data/packagename/mydownload`

   The below code may help you.

   ```
   fileName = fileName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9- _,()]+","")+ ".(your format example PDF)";

       client = new DefaultHttpClient();

           request = new HttpGet(URL);



       response = client.execute(request);



       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       String PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/mydownload/";
       File file = new File(PATH);
       file.mkdirs();



       final long lenghtOfFile = entity.getContentLength();
       File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);

       Log.i("length",lenghtOfFile +fileName);
       //if(outputFile.exists())   {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

       InputStream  is = entity.getContent();



       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int len1 = 0;
       long total = 0;


       while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           fos.write(buffer, 0, len1); 

           }

       }
       fos.close();
       is.close();
   ```